# File upload in angularjs not stored in it's original format

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I am trying to upload a single word/pdf file in the server. I have used the sample given in this link www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm

The process grabs the file and puts it in the specified place, but the problem is it's in a different format or unreadable format.

The format of the file is as shown in the image[file stored in the uploads folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujalf.png)

Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: you're trapped in the Windows world. Just because it's missing a file ending doesn't mean it is in the wrong Format. Did you try renaming it?

Comment: EasterBunnyBugSmasher it worked. Thanks for pointing out the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in the comment by "EasterBunnyBugSmasher". Renaming the file worked. While uploading a file through website, the response renames the file with a randomly generated number.